# GEE Select only one band in my imagecollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want that all the images in my imagecollection will contain only one band ('VH_Filtered'). 
The problem is that  whenever I ask GEE to display the images in the imagecollection, I can see that the images display the original band and not the VH_Filtered and I don't understand why.

This is my code:

```
//Filter the collection for the VH product from the descending track


var Sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
        .select('VH')
        .filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-11-12')
        .filterBounds(geometry);

//Clip the image collection

var clippedVH= Sentinel1.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
}); 

//apply Filter

var filterSpeckles = function(img) {
  var vh = img.select('VH') ;//select the VH polarization band
  var VH_smoothed = vh.focal_median(35,'circle','meters').rename('VH_Filtered'); //Apply a focal median filter
  return img.addBands(VH_smoothed); // Add filtered VH band to original image
};


var Clipped_Speckles = clippedVH.map(filterSpeckles);
print(Clipped_Speckles);

//check that speckle filter worked
var list_before=clippedVH.toList(clippedVH.size());
var list_after=Clipped_Speckles.toList(Clipped_Speckles.size());


var before=ee.Image(list_before.get(0));
var after=ee.Image(list_after.get(0)).clip(geometry).select('VH_Filtered');



//Map.addLayer(before,{min: -30, max: 1},'Before');
//Map.addLayer(after,{bands: 'VH_Filtered',min: -30, max: 1},'after');




// var clippedVHsize=clippedVH.size();
// print('SAR Size:',clippedVHsize);
// print('SAR images data:',clippedVH);

var listOfImagesSAR =(Clipped_Speckles.toList(Clipped_Speckles.size()));

var NumberOfImagesSAR=listOfImagesSAR.size();

var listOfNumbersSAR = ee.List.sequence(0, NumberOfImagesSAR.subtract(2));
listOfNumbersSAR = listOfNumbersSAR.map(function(n) {
  return ee.Number(n).add(1);
});
print(typeof(listOfNumbersSAR));
listOfNumbersSAR=listOfNumbersSAR.getInfo();




for (var i in listOfNumbersSAR) {
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImagesSAR.get(listOfNumbersSAR[i]));
  var toexport=image.visualize({min: -30, max: 1}).addBands(image);


  //Add the layer- here I can see it didnt work
  Map.addLayer(image,{min: -30, max: 1},'SAR'+ i);
  // Export.image.toDrive({
  // image: toexport.toFloat(),
  // description: i,
  // scale:10,
  // crs:'EPSG:4326',
  // maxPixels:1310361348,
  // region:geometry.geometry().bounds()

// });


}
```

The area is in Thailand so any polygon there wouold work.

my end goal: to have imagecolelction with only one band.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images you are displaying are from your `Clipped_Speckles`, and `filterSpeckles` creates those images by adding a band called `'VH_Filtered'` to the existing bands (the one band `'VH'`). So if you want only that band, you should `return VH_smoothed;` instead of using `addBands` at all.

If you want to keep the `'VH'` band around for further processing, but display `VH_Filtered` on the map, then you need to either do a `select` before displaying the image (I see you have a suitable `select` on the line that starts `var after=ee.Image...` but that isn't being used later so it doesn't have any effect); or you could specify the bands in the visualization parameters to `Map.addLayer`:

```
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['VH_Filtered'], min: -30, max: 1});
```